# R - draw line between two specific values in plot in R

Tags: r, plot, lines

I need to draw a line between two specific values from a plot in R. That's what I want. If it is possible to draw a line between those two consecutive values which the difference between values is higher than 3. Else, draw it knowing the values from the dataset. Also, I would like to add a number under or above the line. Thanks.
Here the link where you can find the image "ImageR.png"

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/blnr3jvius8f3eh/AACOhqyzZGiDHAOPmyE__873a?dl=0

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do. Can you please try to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it. You may have to play with `pos` and `offset` in `text` to get it to look good on your data.

```
x <- rnorm(20, sd=3)
d <- diff(x)

plot(x)

for (i in which(d>3)) {
  lines(c(i,i+1), x[i:(i+1)])
  text(i+.5, mean(x[i:(i+1)]), round(d[i],1), pos=2)
}
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thanks @Josh. Exactly what I was looking for.